# Linq to SQL - Vb.net date time

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to display Datetime.Minvalue if LastLogon Date is null in my Linq to SQL query.

```
Dim ExtUsrsQry = 
    (From qryItem In dc1.ExternalUserAccesses                                
     Where qryItem.QuarterId = GetCurrentQuarterId()
     Select Id = qryItem.Id,
         LastLogonDate = IIf((qryItem.LastLogonDate.HasValue), Convert.ToDateTime(qryItem.LastLogonDate).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString())
     ).ToList()
```

It is not working. How can I fix this query?

Comment: You are missing a `)`. Insert it before `.ToList()`

Comment: I removed additional lines of code while pasting here to make it look simple. I must have missed it when I copy over here.

Comment: What type is `ExternalUserAccesses.LastLogonDate`? The full db type including whether it is nullable (I guess it is)

Comment: Its a datetime and allows nulls

Comment: Then why are you doing `Convert.ToDateTime(qryItem.LastLogonDate)` if it's already a datetime? That should be `qryItem.LastLogonDate.Value` without any Conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `NULL DATETIME` coming from SQL, which is a `DateTime?` in .Net. Your code would be much simpler and clearer if you use [null coalescence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator#if-operator-called-with-two-arguments)

```
Dim ExtUsrsQry =
    (From qryItem In dc1.ExternalUserAccesses
     Where qryItem.QuarterId = GetCurrentQuarterId()
     Select Id = qryItem.Id, LastLogonDate = If(qryItem.LastLogonDate, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue)
    ).ToList()
```

EDIT

I updated the answer to have the null coalescing If() return `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue` instead of the .Net equivalent.

Comment: I tried the above code - didn't work - An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: There must be some other code in conjunction with this which makes it not work. Once you select the anonymous type after this code are you going back into SQL? This code attempts to return `DateTime.MinValue` which is much earlier than `SQLDateTime.MinValue`. If you must do more with the date (put it back in sql or whatever) then you should use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue`. I'll edit my post.